# on the predict.merMod function arguments

Tags: r, predict, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

In the function `predict.merMod` of the `lme4` package, what is the difference between  the following arguments: `allow.new.levels=TRUE`, `re.form=NA` and `re.form=~0` if we have only a random intercept?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit in response to your edit, but it doesn't make much difference. If you don't understand my answer, perhaps you could clarify/focus your question?

Answer (score 0):

> `re.form`: ...if `NA` or `~0`, include no random effects.

In other words, either of these choices makes predictions for **all** observations (or sets of predictors specified in `newdata`) at the *population level*, setting all random effects to zero.

> `allow.new.levels`: logical if new levels (or `NA` values) in `newdata` are
> allowed. If `FALSE` (default), such new values in `newdata`
> will trigger an error; if `TRUE`, then the prediction will use
> the unconditional (population-level) values for data with
> previously unobserved levels (or `NA`s).

In other words, population-level predictions are made *only* (assuming `re.form` is not `NA` or `~0`) for observations/sets of predictor values where the random-effect grouping variable is `NA` or a level that did not occur in the original data set used to fit. (If only a subset of the grouping variables in a model with multiple of grouping variables are set to `NA`/new values, only the random effects corresponding to those grouping variables will be set to zero [this detail is only relevant if there is more than one random-effect term in the model].)

Comment: So in my case, I think that the setting of the three arguments is equivalent since I have only a random intercept and I don't have the projection level in my original data.  Also when I set re.form=NULL I found better performance in the cross-validation than setting re.form=NA but my problem is I don't have the levels of the future prediction in my original data.

Comment: That sounds about right. Of course you will have better performance if you have access to group-specific information and use it (i.e. `re.form=NULL`) ...

Comment: What I'm thinking to do is to get benefit of this. Use the argument re.form=NULL for the cross-validation and for the future projections (I have raster files) defining a constant year for example: predict(Raster.stack, GLMM, const=(data.frame(Year=2011))). What do you think about this approach?

Comment: I think that's silly if the projections are for future (unknown) years. You should do the cross-validation for the same scenario for which you *actually* want to predict, i.e. `re.form=NA`. You should also be careful about your cross-validation  i.e. consider block cross-validation (see Roberts et al. “Cross-Validation Strategies for Data with Temporal, Spatial, Hierarchical, or Phylogenetic Structure.” *Ecography*, December 1, 2016, n/a-n/a. https://doi.org/10.1111/ecog.02881)